# // SPDX-License-Identifier: error

Tags: solidity, remix

i am forking a contract and came across this error.

```
Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information. --> sal.sol
```

Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version! Consider adding "pragma solidity ^0.8.0;" --> sal.sol

note that: i use "// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT"  and also the same compiler version.

Comment: Which compiler version are you using? Also, you need to provide a copy of the source code for the community to be able to provide proper help.

Comment: i am using safemoon...compiler version, 6.0 .12